# Align element in corner of round Wear device

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I am trying to align an Object into the corner of my round_layout for a round android wear device.
As you can see here:

[image]

The digitalclock will be out of bounds.

I've seen the android wear documentation at the google IO 2014, and some guy showed, that there's a line of code, in order to align the objects correctly.
I want the digitalclock to be in the top left corner, but not out of the screen.

Has anyone got a suggestion?

Here's the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear_round">

<DigitalClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**:

My xml layout file looks like this right now, for the round activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="1234567890"
       app:layout_box="top"/>

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

As You can see, I tried to use the BoxInsetLayout, but still, the output is following:

[image]

Although I used

```
app:layout_box="top"
```

The TextView is out of the screen's bounds. What have I overseen?

Comment: Is that all you have as of now? Have you tried any margins or padding or dynamically shifting the view?

Comment: I could try adding padding or margin etc. but I thought it would be easier if there was another method. I am sure there is, just wanted to know if anybody is familiar with it.

Comment: @user2410644 Please tell whether my solution below works for you:) Or maybe you have any problems implementing it?

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga I've edited my post: It doesn't seem to work for me, I might have overseen something?

Comment: @user2410644 I've just tested this code and it works fine. Please see my updated answer below. If this code doesn't work for you it means that you've probably done something wrong. Maybe you're testing it on "Android Wear Rect" system with "AndroidWearRound" emulator skin? Please make sure that you're testing in on right emulator configuration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According for things shown on Google IO 2014 you should use `BoxInsetLayout`:
[Check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naf_WbtFAlY#t=363) <- about 6:04

You can see the usage of `BoxInsetLayout` in `DelayedConfirmation` sample code. Here is a content of main_activity.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:layout_box="top">

        [...]

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

You can set the app:layout_box to following values: `left|top|right|bottom` or `all`. You can use `all` in your case, then all content will be kept within the box on every side. The effect for this layout is ignored when app is running on square watch.

---

### EDIT:

I've just tested the code you've posted as "doesn't work":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="1234567890"
       app:layout_box="all"/>

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

With activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I've told you to use the `all` value in `layout_box`, but even with `top` it works as should:

### `app:layout_box="top"`: (only offset from top)

[image]

### `app:layout_box="all"`: (offset from any side)

[image]

Comment: ""box" in attribute "layout_box" is not a valid value" what do

Comment: You need to show me your xml layout somehow (maybe post it on http://pastebin.com/ for example). Also make sure that you've included the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` part.

Comment: hmm it seems my sumulator thinks it is a square watch when it's round. what's going on? i think this affecting my previews too

Comment: There is everything fine with your xml code. You meant that you had an error from your IDE? Have you resolved that? The other thing with your emulator: Maybe you have a `Android Wear Square` emulator with `AndroiWearRound` skin attached?

Comment: No, i have remade the emulator multiple times now. No error from my IDE but i think the problems may be linked...

Comment: Right. i just deleted and reinstalled the system images for Wear using the SDK manager and the emulator seems ot have actually fired up with a round display. finally!

Comment: ... So where your error `""box" in attribute "layout_box" is not a valid value"` appears? Can you give me some more details? BTW. You can get rid of the root `RelativeLayout` and leave `BoxInsetLayout` as a root.

Comment: You have to use "all" not "box"

Comment: Argh. I've updated my answer, just stupid typo in code during editing... :)

Comment: As is the case with other layout parameters, the app:layout_box attribute must be added to the child view element, not the BoxInsetLayout element.

Comment: FYI - from my experience, BoxInsetLayout doesn't work for a watchface, nor does WatchViewStub. They both return isRound()=false. The same code works for an actual app. In Google's defense, building watchfaces is more of a hack than anything else until they provide official support for it.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, `BoxInsetLayout` and `WatchViewStub` MUST be the root of your activity's view in order to work! I found out the hard way :(

Comment: I lied! my problem was actually due to my activity's theme! there are only a handful of themes that work with watches. (under `sdk/platforms/android-20/data/res/values-watch/themes_device_defaults.xml`)

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga: code in your answer doesn't work in round wear emulator